# PHP Library to parse Excel files

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I need to find a PHP library that reads/previews Excel files uploaded by a user.

Does anyone know of any PHP Libraries used to parse .xsls files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)?
Great documentation and open source library.